# Perform a calculation between two cells in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Datagrid and I want to perform a calculation on QTY On HAND.
If QtyOnHand < SetMin (Text) or If Qty > SetMax (Text) and palce the result the Status column.  How would I go about doing so.  Every tutorial I have found so far is for a WinForms and doesn't work with a WPF datagrid very well.

I'm a rookie here so I'm not opposed to figure this out if someone is willing to point me in the correct direction.
[image]

I'm populating the grid from a dataset

```
   void mainDataSet()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        con.Close();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.IsReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataContext = ds.Tables[0];

    }
```

Comment: Where is your code? It makes a huge difference. Are you bound to a model? If so do the calculations in a property getter...

Comment: To do what you are asking you need to first pump your dataset into a model. Then, in your models properties you can apply what ever filters you'd like

Comment: Thank you,  Off to go read about models :)

Comment: To help your research the search terms are going to be "MVVM", "Data Binding", "DataGrid DataTemplate", "OnPropertyChanged"

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a property that has the calculation and bind the column to that?
I'm assuming by your notes regarding (Text) that those are actually string values and not decimals... so convert them (is it possible that they will be null?) and compare and return whatever string you like for the status.  Note the example below assumes that setmin and setmax will never be null or fail conversion and if qtyonhand is within the bounds, no status (blank) is returned.

```
public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            decimal _min = Convert.ToDecimal(this.SetMin);
            decimal _max = Convert.ToDecimal(this.SetMax);
            string _status = string.Empty;
            if (this.QtyOnHand < _min)
                _status = "whatever the status is that means not enough on hand.";
            if(this.QtyOnHand > _max)
                _status = "whatever the status is that means too much is on hand.";

            return _status;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Except I am populating the grid with a dataset from a SQL server.

Comment: @eternityhq Take the dataset and populate a class with the data columns mapped to properties. Create a property called Status (above but with INotifyPropertyChange) which builds off of the other properties and reports the status. Then bind to the class in the grid.

Comment: Put in InotifyPropertyChanged operation into the property.

Comment: @OmegaMan  Thank you for your help.  I am going to try your suggestions and I i do get it working correctly I will post the code for everyone else.

Comment: You can also add the property to your SQL query/stored procedure to return the field if that is easier for you.